# Other way to track clicked links in mails? without Link-Level Engagement Splits

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

I try to track if certain link in an email is clicked. I thought best practice is to use Link-Level Engagement Splits. But we are not allowed to have the "wait" period before the "decision split" in Journey builder.

Is there a way to add some AMPScript to the email which updates Data Extension when certain link is clicked? Or do i have to use a _Click query and automation to get this data in my "Main" Data Extension?

Answer (score 0):

AMPScript won't help you, since it's evaluated right before the send occurs, not after.

Click activity is recorded through link wrapping, stored and made accessible in the data views.   You'll have to use a Query Activity to aggregate the click activity data into your "Main" Data Extension.